# Minimize BIRT Runtime library dependencies

Tags: java, maven, birt

At the moment I use standard BIRT Runtime library. It is defined in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This dependency is very huge and weights ~100 Mb. I am going to use only POJOs implementation, so I want to exclude all JDBC, Scripted Data Sources & other unnecessary libraries.

Maybe somebody knows which libraries could I exclude without any risk?

Comment: I dare say it's not worth the effort.What's the problem with <100 MB disk space wasted? Unless you need to deploy all this on each client machine, and even then... For example, my AV software uses 300 MB just for virus signatures, so what?

Answer (score 0):

If is is not documented the usual approach is try-and error. Exclude all dependencies (see Maven documentation how to exclude dependencies) and see what classes are missing (e.g. ClassNotFound/ClassDefNotFound exceptions).

Then step-by step re-enable all dependencies which are required for your use-case until everything works fine again.